# Show Div Every xHours or xDays

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, slide

Two things I'm having trouble with.

I've constructed a notice that slides in when the page loads and slides out after a set amount of time.

Firstly, I don't want it to run every time the page loads because this would annoy the members. Could this be done with cookies? If so, how?

Secondly, I'd like to make the `<div>` slide out when the user clicks the close button so they don't have to wait for the script to finish.

Comment: So many answers! I didn't think I'd get this much help ;) I've updated my OP and used theJavaSharp's method for closing the div. I just need to implement it with one of the cookie scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your existing jsFiddle with a basic example of how cookies could be used to record if a user has already seen the popup: http://jsfiddle.net/Jk2AG/27/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if (getCookie("show-slide") == null) {
        $("#dimBackgrnd").hide().delay(1000).fadeIn("slow");

        $("#slide").hide().delay(2000).show("drop", {
            direction: "up"
        }, 500);


        $("#dimBackgrnd").hide().delay(7500).fadeOut("slow");

        $("#slide").delay(6000).hide("drop", {
            direction: "down"
        }, 500);

        setCookie("show-slide", "false", 7);
    }
    else {
        $("#dimBackgrnd").hide();
        $("#slide").hide();
    }

});

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with any type of long term storage.

1. User logs in
2. Check last notification shown date
3. is CurrentDate - LastShownDate > X ? show notification

Answer (score 0):

If you don't store the last notifications date on your server, you could store a cookie on the user's computer which expires after X days. If there is no cookie, you display the message.

Answer (score 0):

Okey Karl!

First check out this: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
With this you should be able of making the cookie-thing.

Then looked at my fiddle, a bit stripped but working great!
http://jsfiddle.net/Jk2AG/28/

Answer (score 0):

My example may be a bit more excessive than needed, because you can create cookies with JavaScript, but I thought I'd show the server-side solution that I would use.

If you're using PHP you can pass it as a session variable on click, let's check it out:

```
$(function(){
  $('#slide #submit').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'cookie_parser.php',
      data: 'setShowSlide=1', //we'll explain 0/1 methodology in the php description
      success: function(data){
        //we could do stuff with the (data) object, but we're not going to. 
        //Instead, we need to check it on page load.
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The PHP to parse the data, set the session, and then return the ID so we can check it.

```
<?php
  session_start(); /* so we can deal with our cookie variables */
  if(!empty($_GET['setShowSlide']) || !empty($_SESSION['setShowSlide'])){
    if(!empty($_GET['setShowSlide']) && empty($_SESSION['setShowSlide'])){
      $setShowSlide = $_GET['setShowSlide']
      if($setShowSlide == 1){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['setShowSlide'] = $setShowSlide;
        return '<input type="hidden" id="setShowSlideCheck" value="'.$_SESSION['setShowSlide'].'">';
      }else if ($setShowSlide != 1){
        return false;
        /* We don't need to return any other instance. If it's not 1, then we're being hijacked, and we want to stop all script execution. */
      }
    }else if(empty($_GET['setShowSlide']) && !empty($_SESSION['setShowSlide'])){
      return '<input type="hidden" id="setShowSlideCheck" value="'.$_SESSION['setShowSlide'].'">';
    }else if(empty($_GET['setShowSlide']) && empty($_SESSION['setShowSlide'])){
      /* Do not do anything. This is default behavior. We want this to display on page load the first time. */
    }
  }
?>
```

In your 'template' file, or 'index.php' file, whatever file you use to continually include javascript/css to maintain your design/flow.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include_once('cookie_parseer.php');
?>
```

In our jQuery, we can now test for the existence of the DOM object, `'setShowSlideCheck'`.

```
$(function(){
  if($('#setShowSlideCheck').length != 0){
    //Don't show the slide, show the slide in variations, more checking to see if user needs to see the slide again, etc.
  }else{
    $("#slide").hide().delay(2000).show("drop", {
        direction: "up"
      }, 500
    );        
    // let's build the click function you wanted now
    $('#slide #submit').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'cookie_parser.php',
        data: 'setShowSlide=1', //we'll explain 0/1 methodology in the php description
        success: function(data){
        //we could do stuff with the (data) object, but we're not going to. 
        //Instead, we need to check it on page load.
        $("#slide").hide('drop', {
            direction: "down"    
          }, 500
        );
        //I'm choosing to hide the above in the callback for the success on ajax request.
        //You can actually do this wherever you like.
      }
    });
  });
  }
});
```

This is general purpose to get you started. the 'click' function is also included as you desired.